# Trying to keep whitespace in a code block

Tags: whitespace, markdown

I'm trying to use markdown to format a web page. Part of the web page has block quotes and code blocks. In some of the code blocks, the leading and trailing white space (empty lines) is important. I can't find much on this and can't figure out how to include the leading and trailing empty lines.

```
> empty_line
> empty_line
> Stuff Here
> empty_line
> empty_line
```

.. if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use HTML tags, have you tried using the pre tags?

```
Stuff 1 here





Stuff 2 here
```

I use `pre` at very top with HTML tag brackets of course and closed that tag at the bottom. Using this tag retains the blank lines + creates a code block as you see.

Comment: This worked for me while putting an ASCII chart in my readme. Cheers!